# which usses much memory hashset or arrays

Tags: java, arrays, performance, memory, hashset

i making a datatype which is called randomQueue which enqueue any object, and it dequeues from it randomly i am using arrays as a basic datatype, so my question is which takes more memory hashset or arrays, then i am implementing this because i will do a random items generator 
the api should be the following

```
enqueue(Item item)
dequeue()
isEmpty()
size()
private resize()
private shrink()
```

the running time should be amortized
i think the performance of both should be the same in both implementations but i am wondering what about the memory and is there any way to calculate the memory used by my program instead of calculating each line of code memory usage ? 
PS i use java.

Comment: What do you mean randomly enqueues and dequeues?

Comment: Hashset is a conceptual data structure. It can be implemented in many ways. including arrays. This question does not make sense.

Comment: sorry for that but what i meant is that it only dequeues randomly, i edited the question.

Comment: my question means that if i have two ways to implement a queue either by hashset or arrays which on to use considering i need to use less memory

Comment: @MohamedShaban Try both, profile, measure, find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a 32-bit HotSpot VM, a `java.util.HashSet` will take about 32 bytes per element, and an array will take about 4.  If you're reimplementing one of those structures, of course, those numbers aren't of any use to you.

Answer (score 0):

The two different structures really pose no significant advantages over each other for memory consumption. A hashset will generally be faster for retrievals over an array since in an array you must iterate through all items until you find the one you are looking for and a hashset is grouped.

Comment: i am not iterating i am getting the index by math.random method and i scale it to the size of the array

Comment: Just use an array then. I don't see any good reason to use a hashset here, but others may disagree.